# Flot Chart using Bubbles

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm using jQuery Flot and the Bubbles plugin to generate the chart shown below.  The chart/bubbles render as expected so long as the Y-axis values are at least 100.  Of course, some of the values I am plotting are <100 and some are even less than 1.  The following jsfiddle shows the sample data sets that work/don't work.

I didn't see anywhere in the Flot or Bubbles documentation where the Y-axis values had to be > 100.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/gstoa/rr3bqz5w/

[image]

```
//var dataEarningsActual =   [[1, 15, 10], [2, 15, 10], [3, 16, 10], [4, 13, 10]];
//var dataEarningsEstimate = [[1, 13, 10], [2, 14, 10], [3, 12, 10], [4, 15, 10]];
var dataEarningsActual =   [[1, 150, 10], [2, 150, 10], [3, 160, 10], [4, 130, 10]];
var dataEarningsEstimate = [[1, 130, 10], [2, 140, 10], [3, 120, 10], [4, 150, 10]];
var dataEarningsPeriods =  [[1,'Q1 2017'], [2,'Q2 2017'], [3,'Q3 2017'], [4,'Q4 2017']];

var optionsEarnings = {
  series: {
    color: "#62CB31",
    bubbles: {
      active: true,
      show: true,
      fill: true,
      linewidth: 2
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    ticks: dataEarningsPeriods,
    autoscaleMargin: 0.25
  },
  yaxis: {
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 10
  },
  grid: {
    tickColor: "#f0f0f0",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'f0f0f0',
    color: '#6a6c6f'
    }

};

$.plot( $("#placeholder"), [ dataEarningsActual, { color: '#6a6c6f', data: dataEarningsEstimate }], optionsEarnings );
```

Comment: The bubbles-plugin works with y-values less than 100. Your problem is, that the bubble-size is too big, so the bubbles fill the chart completely. You can see the problem in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr3bqz5w/5/) with your lower y-values and a bubblesize of 5 instead of 10 which only fills large portions of the chart instead of all of it..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by leveraging Flot's tickFormatter call for the y-axis data values.  To account for incoming decimal values, I have to first multiply each value by 1,000 (server-side) then use the formatter function call to divide by 1000.  Whatever works, I guess.

https://jsfiddle.net/gstoa/rr3bqz5w/

```js
var dataEarningsActual =   [[1, 150, 10], [2, 150, 10], [3, 160, 10], [4, 130, 10]];
var dataEarningsEstimate = [[1, 130, 10], [2, 140, 10], [3, 120, 10], [4, 150, 10]];
var dataEarningsPeriods =  [[1,'Q1 2017'], [2,'Q2 2017'], [3,'Q3 2017'], [4,'Q4 2017']];

function formatter(val, axis) {
 //turns 150 into .15
 return val / 1000; 
}

var optionsEarnings = {
  series: {
    color: "#62CB31",
    shadowSize: 5,
    bubbles: {
      active: true,
      show: true,
      fill: true,
      linewidth: 1
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    ticks: dataEarningsPeriods,
    autoscaleMargin: 0.25
  },
  yaxis: {
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 0,
    tickDecimals: 2,
    tickFormatter: formatter
  },
  grid: {
    tickColor: "#f0f0f0",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'f0f0f0',
    color: '#6a6c6f'
 }

};
```